# unity visual studio android debugger over USB

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, debugging, adb, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to debug on my android device (samsung s7) over USB a unity project using Visual studio 2019. However when I follow the steps described here.

I have my android device listed when I do a adb devices -l.

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/vscode-unity-debug/issues/44

I don't have the Android player listed in the Debug > Attach unity debugger windows.

I have also setup my drivers like described here:

http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/

I don't know what else to try. Does anybody has the same problem and just uses wifi debugging?

**EDIT 1:**

Trying with VS2017 doesn't work either

**EDIT 2:**

Trying with a samsung S9 is actually working.

**EDIT 3:**

tested with a razor and it also worked

It looks like VS2019 can't find my samsung S7 SM G930U and only this device for some reason. I'll investigate further to check why.

Comment: See checklist here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272891/android-device-and-unity-connection-failure/68180675#68180675

Answer (score 1):

I don't know with visual studio 2017. But i got the same issue with vs2019.How i solved the issue is first,
if you are doing fresh installation of the visual studio then select the following components:
1)USB device connectivity.
2)Android SDK setup(API Level 30) .(i selected 30 but you can choose your own)
3)OpenJDK(Microsoft Distrubution).

Or even if the visual studio is installed .
Go to:

1. visual studio installer
   2)On installed version of visual studio click on modify .
   3)Go to individual components and install the above mentioned components.

I think this will solve the issue.

Thank you.